# convert NSData to mp4 file

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsdata, mp4

I use NSURLConnection to download remote mp4 file and write data to app directory, then play them.

If I convert the NSData in this delegate method, everything is ok

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
      [responseData writeToFile:path 
               atomically:YES];
}
```

But if I want to convert NSData in below delegate method, for example I just want the first half of Mp4, then something wrong, the Mp4 file  cannot play

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
      [responseData writeToFile:path 
               atomically:YES];
}
```

Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that will be wrong.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

This delegate method will be called *after* the whole audio data has been downloaded, if you convert the audio file it will be fine.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

But this delegate method will be called every time the app received data.  The “data” is a portion of the whole data, of course it can't be converted.

Comment: If I just want the first half of NSData, how can I convert this to Mp4?